# Como adicionar uma classe a multiplos elementos em cache de uma só vez?

Tags: jquery, refatoração, addclass

Em jQuery, podemos adicionar classes de CSS a múltiplos elementos, mas com o elemento já em cache numa variável, como podemos realizar a mesma operação?

### Exemplo:

```js
// adicionar classe a ambos os elementos
$('#myEle, #anotherEle').addClass('johnDoe');
```

### Elementos em cache:

```js
var $ele1 = $('#myEle'),
    $ele2 = $('#anotherEle');

// adicionar classe a ambos os elementos
$ele1.addClass('johnDoe');
$ele2.addClass('johnDoe');
```

Como passar para uma linha a adição de uma classe de CSS ao `$ele1` e `$ele2` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery contém um método, o [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/), que permite agrupar vários objectos de jQuery que representam um grupo de elementos do DOM num único objecto:

[Documentação da API jQuery: .add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

### Exemplo:

```js
var $ele1 = $('#myEle'),
    $ele2 = $('#anotherEle');

// adicionar classe a ambos os elementos
$ele1.add($ele2).addClass('johnDoe');
```

Trabalhando com elementos já em cache, será util saber que podes colocar em cache o `$ele1` e o `$ele2` para o caso de serem chamados várias vezes:

```js
var $elements = $ele1.add($ele2);

$elements.addClass('johnDoe');
```

Comment: boa, não conhecia essa classe para trabalhar mais de um elemento por vez...

Comment: @LeandroLUK, Pois, eu descobri a mesma quando coloquei a pergunta/resposta :)